# Uma tabela de telefone para cada cliente ou uma só para todos clientes?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Atualmente na faculdade aprendemos assim:

Tem uma entidade cliente, esse cliente tem seus atributos e um deles é o telefone, quero que seja possível o cadastro de vários telefones, criamos uma só tabela, nela vai ter o id do cliente e o telefone, assim podemos cadastrar vários telefones com o mesmo `id` do cliente.

Não fica mais pesado pra fazer a pesquisa dos telefones de um só cliente? Vai ficar tudo junto os telefones dos clientes em uma só tabela.

Nas empresas fazem desse jeito? Ou cada cliente terá uma tabela própria na hora que um novo é cadastrado?

Comment: Sua pergunta recebe a resposta mais genérica que exite (rs), DEPENDE DE CADA CASO. Quando você fala "Nas empresas" depende de cada empresa, não dá para comparar uma estrutura de armazenamento como a do Google por exemplo com a estrutura da lojinha do bairro (exemplo extremo eu sei). Em resumo para mim um join entre cliente e telefone (se bem indexado) é mais factível (contanto que esteja dentro da necessidade do projeto)

Comment: estuda sobre modelagem de dados no banco, vai te esclarecer todas essas duvidas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se existisse uma regra única já teria tudo pronto e não precisaria ninguém mais pra fazer. As empresas não pagam programadores para fazer o que já está feito. Programadores são pagos para criar a melhor solução para aquele problema específico, o problema dela, que atende todos os requisitos, e geralmente o desenvolvedor é que deve achar esses requisitos, inclusive os que nem o usuário sabe. Por isso não importa o que alguém já fez, ou se muitos o fazem assim.

O que costuma ser certo é ter vários telefones na própria tabela do cliente. Simples assim, e rápido. Raro ver um motivo para que os telefones sejam cadastrados em outra tabela, e se acha que deve fazer isso deve achar uma boa justificativa. Tabela extra sempre custa mais caro e deve-se evitar até que traga um benefício compensador. Seu caso tem um benefício assim?

Mas se separar não vejo problema algum em fazer como está pensando. Se você vê, deveria justificar. Se fizer certo não é lento.

E se está dizendo que cada cliente deve ter uma tabela só pra cadastrar esses telefones, a resposta é um definitivo não. Se tiver 1 milhão de clientes você vai criar 1 milhão de tabelas só pra os telefones? Isto não faz sentido e provavelmente esbarrará em um problema técnico além de ficar inadministrável.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, o exemplo do telefone foi bem básico, me surgiu essa dúvida porque parece demorado pesquisar uma tabela inteira para achar os itens só daquele id do cliente dentre possivelmente milhares.

Comment: Não se fizer certo.

Answer (score 1):

O cenário que está colocando deve ser pensado em relação ao SGBD (Sistema Gerenciador de Banco de Dados) que irá utilizar, mais especificamente, o modelo de SGBD.

Vou considerar dois modelos: [Relacional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banco_de_dados_relacional) (como PostgreSQL) e [Orientado a Documentos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banco_de_dados_orientado_a_documentos) (como MongoDB).

## Modelos Relacionais

Em modelos relacionais, o padrão de boas práticas e modelagem está embasado na [Normalização de dados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados), onde uma das formas normais descreve a necessidade de as propriedades de entidades (campos de uma tabela), não serem multivalorados.

Desta maneira, para resolver, usando o cenário que você citou, um cliente com vários telefones, o ideal é sim criar uma tabela Cliente e uma tabela Telefone onde cada cliente terá *n* telefones e cada telefone pertencerá a 1 cliente, fazendo o relacionamento por chave primária do cliente (id do cliente) ser adicionada como campo de chave estrangeira na tabela de telefones.

Sua dúvida quanto à performance, veja, SGBDs relacionais foram criados para lidar com altos volumes de dados e resolver da forma mais performática possível os relacionamentos entre tabelas. Tecnicamente a solução simples é criar índices para a chave estrangeira, o que permite à engine executar planos inteligentes nos momentos de consultas.

Portanto como exemplo teríamos o modelo a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Modelos Orientados a Documentos

Estão dentre uma categoria mais ampla definida como Modelos Não Relacionais ou NoSQL, especificamente os Orientados a Documentos permitem a modelagem de dados de um documento inteiro como um registro em uma coleção (nome dado às tabelas).

MongoDB por exemplo armazena um documento no formato BSon (Binary Json) e permite, na verdade na maioria dos casos, orienta, a "desnormalização" de dados, isto é, no caso específico de campos multivalorados, eles são bem-vindos.

Veja, como os bancos relacionais, estes também são projetados para lidar com altos volumes de dados, mas em geral, por minimizarem a necessidade de resolver relacionamento (joins) entre várias tabelas, a performance em muitos casos é maior pois todos os dados estão armazenados juntos.

Por exemplo para Cliente e telefones, o modelo poderia ser com o campo Telefones armazenando um array:

```
Cliente {
   nome: "João",
   cpf: "00000000000",
   telefones: ["42-9999-9999", "41-0000-9999"]
}
```

## Cuidado com a modelagem

Por fim, concordo com @maniero quando é enfático quanto à usar uma tabela ou coleção de telefone para cada cliente, isto sim seria totalmente fora de contexto, pois teria de criar tabelas por exemplo: Telefone_1, Telefone_2, Telefone_X, uma para cada cliente, inviável do ponto de vista técnico prático, e totalmente fora de qualquer orientação de boa prática e literatura tanto na modelagem de dados Relacionais como NoSQL.